Error: TypeError: page.setInputFiles is not a function
I use Puppeteer version: 23.2.1
And when I want to call the setInputFiles function I got :
Error: TypeError: page.setInputFiles is not a function
Here is a sample code :
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function testSetInputFiles() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
        headless: false, 
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] 
    });

    
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    try {
        await page.goto('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_file_upload_button.asp');

        // Wait for the file input element and then set the file
        await page.waitForSelector('input[type="file"]');
        await page.setInputFiles('input[type="file"]', '/path/to/your/file.jpg');

        console.log('File uploaded successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
}

testSetInputFiles();

Weird, because Visual Studio find the method :

Any clue?

Look into https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page setInputFiles does not exist in Page API, and I guess, it was removed long ago. Unstead of this you can just use uploadFile function from element directly. const input = await page.waitForSelector('input[type="file"]'); await input.uploadFile('path/to/file')

Thanks for self-answering, but please post your self-answer as an answer, not an edit. No need to say edit:.

You might want to add a language tag to this, probably "javascript", plus perhaps "node.js".

So,here is the answer :
setInputFiles is deprecated.
You should use :
const elementHandle = await page.$("input[type=file]");
await elementHandle.uploadFile('path/to/file');
